# how to import github or other internet code (project) into java project

Tags: java, import, parse-platform

I need to put some variable code from internet into my project. Any libraryes, plugins, etc if needed (I use gradle and parse/parse4j). I am newbie in java, but have some skills with javascript, so i know how code works. So this is how it shoud like: i have my varible project at github.com/account/rep or something like that, than i need to put that stuff into my general project. I have project/generalproject.java and project/varible.java project. That shoud be command in varible project like ' command: 'url'; '  or something like that. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJTmT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't really (if we ignore remote classloading) have a way to import code from somewhere else. It doesn't allow you to just import code from GitHub.

#### Pure Java way

Instead, you would first download a JAR (you could also have a repository with compiled class files) of the library you want. You can then add to to your classpath by adding `--class-path` to the command-line of both `java` and `javac`.

If we assume you have a JAR called `myjar.jar` with a class `Util` in the package `somelibrarypackage`, you can import that package like any other package using `import somelibrarypackage.Util;`.
For this to compile, you would need to add `--class-path myjar.jar` to `javac`, for example

```bash
# this assumes MainClass is in the default package
javac --class-path myjar.jar MainClass.java
java --class-path myjar.jar MainClass
```

Technically, there's also the *module path* if you want to use modules/have a `module-info.java`. In that case, you would use `--module-path` instead of `--class-path`.

#### Gradle

Build tools actually do that part for you.
For this, you would first need the library/project you are using to be deployed on Maven Central (or a different Maven repository). Typically, libraries have done that already and include information about their "artifact coordinates" in the README.

Artifact coordinates identify libraries on Maven Central. For each library published, there should be a unique group id and artifact id. Aside from that, there will be a version identifying the version of the library you are using.
For example, JUnit uses the group ID `org.junit.jupiter` and the artifact ID `junit-platform-api`. The latest version of it (at the time of writing this answer) is `5.10.1`.

You can also use [this Website](https://central.sonatype.com/) to search through dependencies on Maven Central and find their artifact coordinates.

Since you are using Gradle, you should have a `build.gradle` files containing a `dependencies` block. In there, you can specify which libraries you want to use using artifact coordinates and it should automatically download them and add them to the classpath.
In order to add a dependency to a Gradle project, you add `implementation 'ARTIFACT_COORDINATES_HERE'` where you replace `ARTIFACT_COORDINATES_HERE` with the group ID followed by a `:`, the artifict id, another `:` and the version. For example, for JUnit, this would be:

```
implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.1'
```